# Открывать страницы в зависимости от выбора

Tags: javascript, html

Есть главная страница, на ней сделаны `RadioButton` так же имеются другие страницы 1 и 2 как сделать что бы при выборе `RadioButton1` и нажатие кнопки открылась первая страница, а из `RadioButton2`вторая.

Comment: Разве это html?

Comment: Да это HTML <p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio">
тест</p>
<p>

Comment: @Павел Имелось в виду, что для реализации такой логики понадобится `javascript`

Comment: понятно, а можно пример? Так-как я не силён javascript

Comment: Что вы сделали сами сделали для решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `onClick`. К примеру таким образом:

```
<input type="radio" value="http://ya.ru" onclick="window.open(this.value)" />
```

Или

**html:**

```
<input type="radio" id="in1" value="http://ya.ru" />
```

**js:**

```
    var radio = document.getElementById('in1');

    radio.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.open(this.value);
    }, false);
```